# node - handling db errors without crashing

Tags: node.js

Irrespective of the type of database, I can't get a clear picture of best way of handling db errors without crashing the application.

```
e.g connecting with sql

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  connection.execute('select * ...' , values, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
     throw err;
   }
}); 

});
```

In both cases above I am throwing errors which causes node server to crash. 
I want to register the error and respond to the request in a most elegant fashion. Can anyone point in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are throwing an error, someone needs to catch them. If you don't catch them anywhere in your code, it will cause the program to crush.

So basically what you need to do is to wrap the call to your functions with try/catch, and in case you catch- log it and return an apporopriate response to the requester.

Something like:

```
try {
 pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  connection.execute('select * ...' , values, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
     throw err;
   }
 }); 
 });
} catch (error) {
  log(error);
  res.status(500).body("failed to get ... " + err).send();
}
```

I also recommend reading [this blog post](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors), has good explanation about the subject

Comment: Note that this only works assuming synchronous javascript. The question most likely deals with asynchronous js, which does not work with try/catch (the site you linked explicitly states that `"This pattern does NOT work!"`).

Comment: This will not work because you can't catch async exceptions in this way.